# Sonar Scanner with Docker image finds no source files

Tags: docker, sonarqube, sonar-scanner-cli

I run a Sonar analysis, using `sonar-scanner` installed on my workstation:

```
sonar-scanner -Dsonar.host.url=<SONARQUBE_URL> -Dsonar.login=<TOKEN> -Dsonar.projectKey=<SOME_KEY> -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes
```

Everything runs fine. In particuler, the scanner finds 30 source files to analyse.

I run the same Sonar analysis, using the Docker `sonar-scanner-cli` image:

```
(winpty) docker run --rm -e SONAR_HOST_URL=<SONARQUBE_URL> -e SONAR_TOKEN=<TOKEN> -e SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Dsonar.projectKey=<SOME_KEY>  -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes" -v `pwd`:/usr/src sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:4.8.0
```

It runs smoothly, but **it does not detect any source file**. Does anybody have a clue?

I added `-Dsonar.sources=.` to `SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS`, to no avail.

I replaced `` `pwd` `` with `/c/Projects/my_project`, to no avail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the file correctly mounted in the container? You can check this by running `docker run --rm -e SONAR_HOST_URL=<SONARQUBE_URL> -e SONAR_TOKEN=<TOKEN> -e SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Dsonar.projectKey=<SOME_KEY>  -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes" -v \`pwd\`:/usr/src sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:4.8.0 ls -lisa`, this should list the content of `/usr/src`.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Turing85. Your response and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33566397/docker-run-v-does-not-work-on-windows-using-docker-toolbox put me on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add a slash  in front of `` `pwd` ``, that is, `` -v /`pwd`:/usr/src `` instead of `` -v `pwd`:/usr/src ``. Therefore the correct command is

```
(winpty) docker run --rm -e SONAR_HOST_URL=<SONARQUBE_URL> -e SONAR_TOKEN=<TOKEN> -e SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS="-Dsonar.projectKey=<SOME_KEY>  -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes" -v /`pwd`:/usr/src sonarsource/sonar-scanner-cli:4.8.0
```